# Dynamic Reference for EC2 Instance Type from Parameter Store in Cloudformation Template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm having some difficulty identifying how to reference the EC2 instance type parameter directly from parameter store.  I've searched high and low, but no luck.

I'm able to reference other parameters like EC2KeyPair, using my method.

I started by creating a parameter in parameter store, using the following command.
`aws ssm put-parameter --name myEC2TypeDev --type String --value "t2.small"`

In the CF template, I defined the InstanceType parameter.

```
"InstanceType" : {
  "Description" : "WebServer EC2 instance type",
  "Type" : "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>",
  "Default" : "myEC2TypeDev",
  "AllowedValues" : [ "t1.micro", "t2.nano", "t2.micro", "t2.small", "t2.medium", "t2.large", "m1.small", "m1.medium", "m1.large", "m1.xlarge", "m2.xlarge", "m2.2xlarge", "m2.4xlarge", "m3.medium", "m3.large", "m3.xlarge", "m3.2xlarge", "m4.large", "m4.xlarge", "m4.2xlarge", "m4.4xlarge", "m4.10xlarge", "r5.large", "c5.large", "c5.xlarge", "c1.medium", "c1.xlarge", "c3.large", "c3.xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c3.4xlarge", "c3.8xlarge", "c4.large", "c4.xlarge", "c4.2xlarge", "c4.4xlarge", "c4.8xlarge", "g2.2xlarge", "g2.8xlarge", "r3.large", "r3.xlarge", "r3.2xlarge", "r3.4xlarge", "r3.8xlarge", "i2.xlarge", "i2.2xlarge", "i2.4xlarge", "i2.8xlarge", "d2.xlarge", "d2.2xlarge", "d2.4xlarge", "d2.8xlarge", "hi1.4xlarge", "hs1.8xlarge", "cr1.8xlarge", "cc2.8xlarge", "cg1.4xlarge"],
  "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
}
```

When I execute the template, I get the following error returned:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack
>   operation: Parameter InstanceType failed to satisfy constraint: must
>   be a valid EC2 instance type.

Answer (score 2):

If your resource type is stored on SSM (such as `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value`), the value provided needs to be the name of the parameter on SSM (such as `myEC2TypeDev`). Therefore, your list of `AllowedValues` is probably causing a conflict and raising the error.

Please remove the `AllowedValues` property and try again.